# On Android, how do you get the data from an email address in Firebase, then access the child, and from there you access the other Firebase data?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

The following file explains better what I really mean. It's a screenshot of data sent from a dummy user in Firebase:

[image]

The code:

```
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
                // ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                ref.orderByChild("Email").equalTo("testing3@testing.com").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            String key = datas.getKey();
                            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(key);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), key, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                    String name = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString();
                                    String state = dataSnapshot.child("State").getValue().toString();
                                    String stateRegion = dataSnapshot.child("StateRegion").getValue().toString();
                                    String telephone = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("Telephone").getValue());
                                    nameEditText.setText(name);
                                    stateEditText.setText(state);
                              stateRegionEditText.setText(stateRegion);     
                               telephoneEditText.setText(telephone);
                                }
                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Please, can some person help?

More information about data stored in the Firebase:

[image]

Comment: Is that ID a direct child of your root reference?

Comment: Hello, Alex. Yes, it is. Could you help, please?

Comment: Do you also have other similar children under the root or is the single one? Please show us a more detailed screenshot.

Comment: Hello, Alex. I inserted in the text, a new screenshot with more detailed informations about Firebase, ok? Please, could you check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because I cannot see a more detailed database schema of yours, I assume that all those user objects are direct children under your `Users` node, and also assuming that you want to find the user that has the `Email` set to `testing3@tesing.com`, to display his particular details, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = db.child("Users");
Query queryUsersByEmail = usersRef.orderByChild("Email").equalTo("testing3@testing.com");
queryUsersByEmail.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String name = ds.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", name);
                String state = ds.child("State").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", state);
                String stateRegion = ds.child("State Region").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", stateRegion);
                String telephone = ds.child("Telephone").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", telephone);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
Paul SMith
Rio de Janeiro
Rio de Janeiro
(00)00000-0000
```

Comment: "I assume that all those user objects are direct children under your Users node, and also assuming that you want to find the user that has the Email set to testing3@tesing.com"
Yes. You understood me exactly. I will test your code, and then I will get back to you, ok? :)

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Yep, give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: "really did not work" doesn't provide enough info so I can further help. What exactly didn't work? Do you have any errors? Please provide more info. Please also edit your question to see what you have tried.

Comment: Hello, Alex. Testing your code, it did not work. Could you please test yourself? :)
Entering your code, and clicking the button, nothing is printed. Not in logcat.

Comment: I tested myself. Add the code I have provided you inside the onCreate, does it work there? Try to isolate the code before using any other clicks or logic.

Comment: So, does it work now?

Comment: It did not work.  It must be some error in my Android Studio or in my Firebase. I will try continuing until it works.
Thank you very much anyway, Alex.
You helped me a LOT.

Comment: Ok, keep me posted with your progress.